# Algorithm(or C++): Finding Subset of indexes of 2 arrays to reach end of them by jumping

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, recursive-type

Given two arrays(a,b containing only 2 decimal values), we can either move.

> i+value or i-value. Where value is the element at that index in that array.

We need to reach the last element by traversing each element only once and we start with 1st element.

Now how can we find out subset of values to exchange between a and b so that we can reach the last index.

> eg a = 112 b = 212 here both can reach the end so empty set will also do. Any other set isn't there that will do. So ans will be : {} only.
>
> Eg 2: a= 2211 b= 1111. Here both string can iterate and reach last element. Now if I replace (1,2) indexes in a and b I.e now a=1111 and b= 2211 both the strings can still reach the end . Similarly we can also replace {3},{4},{3,4} and we can still go to last index in both strings.

Now is there a algorithm to do so ?
How can we find out these subsets ?
Maybe a dp Solution ? I would be thankful if someone can guide me through the code if possible.

Comment: Can you give example where resultant subset is not null?

Comment: a=2211 b=1111 this will have many subsets like {1,2} , {1,2,4},{3} and so on.

Comment: The statement of the problem is not clear. The way I understand it, the example in the question has 8 possible answers, and every one of those answers should work.

Comment: @user3386109 can you please tell me the answer you came upon ?

Comment: @ShashwatKumar I gave another example. Check it out.

Comment: Perhaps a better example would be `a={3,3,3,1,3,1}` and `b={1,1,1,3,1,3}`. That way, neither string can iterate to reach the end, so you actually have a problem to solve. If I understand the problem correctly, there are 8 solutions.

Comment: @user3386109 yes. The answer will always be power of 2.